# Sorting pandas rows based on sum of columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a pandas dataset that is randomly ordered.

| Index | Adj | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | +1 | 15 |
| 2 | +1 | 16 |
| 3 | -1 | 14 |
| 4 | -1 | 15 |

I need to re-order it such that the value in the column Stock follows an order given by Stock in row n is Stock in row n-1 + Adj in row n.
This must be done without re-calculating the data but by reordering the rows (all the corrects rows exist but they are not ordered properly)

Here is what the sorted table should look like  (note the value of stock in n+1 = value of stock in n + Adj in n+1)

| Index | Adj | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 16 |
| 2 | -1 | 15 |
| 3 | -1 | 14 |
| 4 | +1 | 15 |

How would you do that in pandas?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is not actually sorting, at least not any efficient sorting that I know of. With repeated values the are many many partial sorts that won't necessarily lead to a valid sorting order. Think of all the combinations of rows that may be partially sorted. Which one would you pick so that the remainder of the rows have a valid sorting solution?

Comment: With your example, it seems you have at least two possible "sorted" results : [1,16], [-1,15], [-1,14], [1,15]) and then ([1,15], [1,16], [-1,15],  [-1,14]). Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Christophe, I agree. Looks like some sort of dynamic programming problem to me.

Comment: @Christophe your second example is invalid, you can't go from 15 to 15 unless adj is 0. This looks like a graph problem, you can compute Stock-Adj to know all possible preceding nodes

Comment: @mozway, you are right. I corrected the second example.

Comment: @Christophe the graph is cyclic you have 4 solutions but the edges are the same ;)

Comment: @mozway, you are right again ;-)

Comment: @@Christophe - Good point. The solution is probably not unique. Unless perhaps if have the stock value that started it all (15 = 16-1 in this case).